# Quickfixn c# MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh but cannot get market data

Tags: quickfix, quickfixn

I am getting market data via quickfixN open source project and using  MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh project. I set 1 minute between the start and end times on config file.System logged out at end time and logged on in 1 minute later. No problem so far...
But I'm not able to get market data. I'm only getting heartbeat data.
**Any ideas why I can't get the market data?**

Config File

```
[DEFAULT] 
PersistMessages=Y 
ConnectionType=initiator
UseDataDictionary=Y
FileStorePath=store 
FileLogPath=log 

[SESSION] 
ConnectionType=initiator
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0
TransportDataDictionary= C:\FIXT11.xml
AppDataDictionary= FIX50.xml 
SenderCompID=COMPANY
SenderSubID=COMPANY.SUB
TargetCompID= TARGET_COMPANY
SenderLocationID=QUOTE
SocketConnectHost= 127.0.0.1
SocketConnectPort= 2003
StartTime= 09:26:00
EndTime= 09:25:00
HeartBtInt=20
ReconnectInterval=30
ResetOnLogon=Y
ResetOnLogout=Y 
ResetOnDisconnect=Y
ResetSeqNumFlag=Y
```

Comment: Read your counter party's docs. Maybe you need to subscribe to market data first? E.g. by sending a `MarketDataRequest`.

Comment: What is "MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh project"?  I see you are connecting to `127.0.0.1` -- are you running an acceptor on another port?

Comment: Many thanks for your comments @ChristophJohn and Grant Birchmeier. Counterparty sent to me info.   While in the test environment it was enough to subscribe to the exchange rate codes only once, I had to subscribe every time I logon the prod environment.

Comment: So is this solved? If yes, you could answer your own question.

Comment: Yes, it is solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counterparty sent to me info. While in the test environment it was enough to subscribe to the exchange rate codes only once, I had to subscribe every time I logon the prod environment.
I added subscribe code in OnLogon method. It is solved.

```
 public void OnLogon(SessionID sessionID)
 {
    LogFix.Info("Logon - " + sessionID.ToString());
    RunQueryMarketDataRequest();
 }
```